# Passwordless account generation in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'd like people to be able to initially use a meteor app without explicitly creating an account until such time as they wished to share their data or see their data on another device.  Even when they were happy to explicitly create an account, I'd like the option for that user account to be passwordless (i.e. https://passwordless.net/).

But I'm struggling at the first hurdle.  How do I check that a user account doesnt already exist and create one if necessary?

Comment: Part of the problem is that `passwordless` is designed for node.js/Express and not Meteor.  Basically you need to find or write a Meteor package for it.

Comment: Yes I'd come to the same conclusion @Paul re: package.  At the moment I'm trying to see how much I can lean on meteor-accounts.

Comment: I have made a 'play as guest' option which creates account and log the user in - can you settle with that?

Comment: That sounds like a good place to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few packages which look promising:

- https://github.com/artwells/meteor-accounts-guest/
- https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-accounts-anonymous

If neither of those are exactly what you want then they should at least provide a good starting point.

An alternate would be to use `accounts-password` and automatically create a unique user account for the guest once they perform some important action so you can store their data.  Store the login credentials for that account in localStorage (or a cookie).  Then once they are ready to signup, move their data from their temp account to their real account and delete the temp one.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else stumbles upon this: Meteor has since released its own password-less solution: https://docs.meteor.com/packages/accounts-passwordless

`meteor add accounts-passwordless` and then follow the instructions in the documentation (link above).